# bundling failed: Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, babeljs

Getting this error after push and clone from bitbucket, previously existing project running fine, after clone from bitbucket did `npm install` and `.babelrc` file exist in the root directory.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Steps tried :

- `npm install babel-preset-react-native-stage-0 --save`
- `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-react-native@2.1.0`

But getting same error on the screen.

Screen shot :

[image]

Comment: how did you solved it??

Answer (score 8):

I too was getting the same problem while I was trying to run an old react-native project. I am just starting to learn react-native and hence was experimenting with an old project from a colleague.

After reading above answers I finally solved this issue

There were lot of files in the root folder of which two were:

1. .babelrc
2. babel.config.js

containing following things:

**.babelrc**

```
{ 
 "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
 presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

I didn't knew either of them. But I tried following above answers and commented out **.babelrc** contents like this:

```
{ 
 // "presets": ["react-native"]
}
```

Then started the server again and it did run as expected.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I just tried your method and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For me I solved the Issue to remove the second preset:

```
"presets": [
            "react-native"
          ]
```

down in the "plugins"-Section:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-remove-console",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "root": [
              "./src"
            ],
            "alias": {
              "test": "./test",
              "components": "./components",
              "config": "./config",
              "lib": "./lib"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "presets": [
        "react-native"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your presets to this

```
"presets": [
    "react-native-stage-0"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-react-native-stage-0), though you install **babel-preset-react-native-stage-0**, your preset should be **react-native-stage-0** or **react-native-stage-0/decorator-support**.

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0"]
}
```

Do you want/need experimental legacy decorator support (provided by babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy)? Use this as your .babelrc instead:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"]
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Deleting .babelrc file will fix this for you.